# Multi Table Query Access Comparing Data

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have three tables, one called Person, one called Owner and the other called Tenant. All three have SSN as one of the fields. What I want to do is compare the SSN from Person (that's the whole list) to see which ones do not show up in either OWner or Tenant so I can see which people in the database have never owned a unit or leased a unit. Then i would like to be able to delete these people out of the person table.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do this is using `not in`:

```
select p.*
from persons as p
where p.ssn not in (select ssn from owner) and
      p.ssn not in (select ssn from tenant);
```

Comment: This is the mark of a true professional in the field, which will give a solution without supplied code, and only from an explanation to a problem. +1 and then some.